# Date Time formatting in scala error: "text could not be parsed at index 0"

Tags: scala, timestamp, java-time

I'm trying to parse a string into a timestamp using java.time.format. I am expected it to be in this format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss".  Here is my code.

```
val timeString = "Mon Sep 20 15:57:56 BST 2021"
val formatFinal = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
val startTs = formatFinal.parse(timeString)
```

However i'm getting this error and I'm not sure why. I'm new to scala/java so may have missed something obvious.

```
 Text 'Mon Sep 20 15:57:56 BST 2021' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Comment: Ham, do you realize your data do not correspond to the pattern you are using?

Comment: should i be using `val formatFinal = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")` instead?

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
import java.time.format.{DateTimeFormatter => DTF}

val timeString = "Mon Sep 20 15:57:56 BST 2021"
val formatFinal = DTF.ofPattern("E LLL dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
val startTs = formatFinal.parse(timeString)

//val startTs: java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor = {InstantSeconds=1632113876},ISO,Pacific/Bougainville resolved to 2021-09-20T15:57:56
```

I'm not sure that's the result you want, but it parses the `timeString`.

Answer (score 2):

To parse date from string to `LocalDateTime`
and back to string in different format you need to have 2 formatters, first one to read the date from string and parse it to `LocalDateTime` and the other one to write `LocalDateTime` back to string in the format you want.

```
val timeString = "Mon Sep 20 15:57:56 BST 2021"
val formatSource = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
val formatOuput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
val startTs = LocalDateTime.parse(timeString, format).format(formatFinal)
```

Comment: Since the source string contains time zone information (though ambiguous), I would see if I could correctly parse into a `ZonedDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime` not to miss any information. I would also definitely provide a locale for the formatter since the string is in English and we would like the code to work on on-English installations too.