# Parsing LocalDate but getting DateTimeParseException; dd-MMM-uuuu

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, datetimeformatter, datetimeparseexception

I am trying to convert a `String` to `LocalDate` using `DateTimeFormatter`, but I receive an exception:

> `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`: Text '**2021-10-31**' could not be parsed at index 5

My code is

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu");
String text = "2021-10-31";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);
```

I am trying to convert from input date `2021-10-31` to `31-Oct-2021`.

Comment: How does “10” match the pattern of MMM? In fact, how does 2021 match “dd”?

Comment: It has been voted to close this question as not reproducible or caused by a typo. Doing so would be wrong. The problem asked about is trivially reproducible always and was not caused by a typo. On the contrary this question is about an error that is not uncommon (trying to use the desired output format for parsing the input), so it will be useful and valuable to keep this question around for future reference.

Comment: Related question, but about Scala: [Date Time formatting in scala error: "text could not be parsed at index 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256650/date-time-formatting-in-scala-error-text-could-not-be-parsed-at-index-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Whats wrong?

> What Am I doing wrong in my code.

Your code specifies the pattern `dd-MMM-uuuu`, but you attempt to parse the text `2021-10-31` which does not fit this pattern at all.

The correct pattern for your string would be `yyyy-MM-dd`. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of the formatter for details.

In particular, watch the order of the days and months `dd-MMM` vs `MM-dd`. And the amount of months `MMM`. A string matching your current pattern would be `31-Oct-2021`.

---

### Change pattern

From the comments:

> my input date is - 2021-10-31 need to covert into - 31-Oct-2021

You can easily change the pattern of the date by:

1. Parsing the input date using the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd`
2. and then format it back to string using the pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

In code, that is:

```java
DateTimeFormatter inputPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTimeFormatter outputPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");

String input = "2021-10-31";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(text, inputPattern);

String output = date.format(outputPattern);
```

Comment: my input date is  -  2021-10-31 need to covert into - 31-Oct-2021

Comment: @Arooshi Parse the input date using the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd` and then format it back to string using the pattern `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Comment: Your code prints `31-10月-2021`.

Comment: @saka1029deleted You have to set the locale to english if you want to get english month names. In chinese, japanese, ... you will just get `日`, `月` and so on.

Comment: @saka1029deleted Please read the documentation of `DateTimeFormatter` that I linked in my answer. There is `ofPattern(..., locale)`, `withLocale(locale)` and `localizedBy(locale)`, So for example `ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Answer (score 4):

#### You do not need to use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your input string

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. Note that your date string is already in ISO 8601 format.

You need a `DateTimeFormatter` just to format the `LocalDate` obtained by parsing the input string.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2021-10-31");
        System.out.println(date);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(date.format(dtfOutput));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-31
31-Oct-2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NKYhac)

Make sure to use `Locale` when using a `DateTimeFormatter`. Check [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573) to learn more about it.

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.</sup>